# Advices aren't woven into class files across modules

Tags: java, aspect

I have problem with AspectJ, I wanted to create 2 jar files. One is file with aspects and logic, while second is with MVC service. I have two modules:

```
logger-client
logger-service
```

inside module client

```
@Aspect
public class AspectTesting {

   @Pointcut("execution(* * (..))")
   public void allServices2() {
   }

   @Before("allServices2()")
   public void executee(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
       System.out.println("Advice woken" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
   }
}
```

and module service

```
 public class Server {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
        testig();
        System.out.println("Hey");
    }

     public void testing() { 
         System.out.println("Aspect woken");
    }
 }
```

All is built with gradle. I have added dependency inside module logger-service

```
  dependencies {
       compile project (":logger-client")
  }
```

and I have added AspectJ inside both gradle files

```
 project.ext {
   aspectjVersion = '1.9.1'
 }
 apply plugin: 'aspectj'
```

Also I have module logger-client added as dependency to logger-service inside IntelliJ. 
Unfortunately, the advice which should be injected before every method is not injected when it's inside different module. It works only when I move Aspect class inside logger-service module.

I tried using annotations. I created "@Logger" annotation inside logger-client module, added proper pointcut to advice and typed this annotation before            "public void testing()"
but same, Aspect is not injected properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. 
Adding "@Component" before Aspect class did job. So now Aspect class looks like:

```
 @Aspect
 @Component
 public class AspectTesting {
      @Pointcut("execution(* * (..))")
      public void allServices2() {
      }

      @Before("allServices2()")
      public void executee(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
          System.out.println("Advice woken" + joinPoint.getSignature().getName());
      }
}
```